# Visual Studio 2022 Breakpoints not hit in Blazor WebAssembly using .NET 8.0

Tags: debugging, blazor, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core project that was recently updated to .NET 8.0, and now I am attempting to add a Blazor WASM project.  I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#enable-interactive-automatic-auto-or-client-side-rendering-csr) to get the project added to my existing ASP.NET Core project (copied the WASM project from a donor project).

The project is an ASP.NET Core project (`MyApp`) which is hosting a Blazor WASM project (`MyApp.Client`).  The Client project has a Page with breakpoints in it. Everything is working *except* debugging the Client app in Visual Studio 2022.

I also created a brand new project using the "Blazor Web App" template (setup the same as the donor project I used) and it **does** successfully break on breakpoints, so I know the browser/environment is correct and its some sort of project configuration issue or something I did wrong when copying the donor project.

Things I've tried/confirmed:

- Hot reloading works
- Visual Studio shows the breakpoints as **bound** (solid red circle)
- Multiple browsers; Chrome/Edge show no errors in the console, Visual Studio reports no errors
- I have followed [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) on debugging:

  - `launchSettings.json` has the correct `inspectUri`
  - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` is referenced by the host project
  - Added a manual delay to `OnInitialized()` to give the time for the debugger to attach (and also tested breakpoints inside of a button click with no success)
- Confirmed with the new working project:

  - My browser works with debugging
  - I have the same directives in `Program.cs`
  - I have the same .NET version, NuGet packages, and startup configuration
- Deleted the bin/obj/.vs folders and restarted VS2022
- Confirmed the project is running in debug mode (I can use breakpoints in the `MyApp` project)
- Confirmed the symbols for the WASM project are being loaded
- `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` does not work either
- Visual Studio is on the latest version (17.8.3)
- I CAN debug the project using the Chrome debugger (shift + alt + D)

I don't know what else to try, any suggestions on what to look for next would be appreciated.

Comment: All I can suggest is to check both the server and client launchsettings;json in the demo solution against the settings in your project very, very carefully.  Make sure the ports are correct.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Do they have to be a specific port?  Our application does overwrite this when building the application (`builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://*:1234");`.  But the launchsettings.json port matches (`"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:1234",`)

Comment: Do you want to debug C# part? If so, please check whether the symbol files(pdb file) has been loaded successfully(You can check this in the logs).

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT VS shows the breakpoint as bound, so I would assume its locating the symbols.  Which logs should I be looking at to confirm this?

Comment: `'MyApp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\repos\MyProject\MyApp\bin\Debug\net8.0\MyApp.Client.dll'. Symbols loaded.` Found what you were referencing, yes the symbols are loaded.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I ended up removing the `UseUrls` and copying the whole launchsettings.json from the working project and it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Without a full view of your setup I don't have any more useful knowledge to offer.